# Mendeley Oauth2 API: Has full-text search been dropped?

Tags: mendeley

With the new Mendeley API, there doesn't seem to be a way to do full-text searches for documents anymore. Is it just not documented? Will it be added? Or is it gone for good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full-text search is something we are currently working on and hoping to release shortly.

Comment: Hows is this coming along... 4 years later?